# FusionCharts Pie3D slice border

Tags: fusioncharts

I need to add a border to slices in FusionCharts *Pie3D* chart.

FusionCharts [API documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/ChartSS/Pie3D.html#Anchor20) states **borderColor** attribute should be added to **set** element in xml data, however it does not seem to have effect.

Here's a sample XML i am feeding the chart:

```
<chart
    decimals="1
    enableSmartLabels="1"
    enableRotation="1"
    startingAngle="70"
    animation="1"
    defaultAnimation="1"
   >
   <set label="Light 1" value="47" isSliced="1" color="ff9999" borderColor="dd3300" />
   <set label="Dark 1" value="53" isSliced="1" color="dd3300" borderColor="dd3300" />

   <set label="Light 2" value="68" isSliced="1" color="ffee99" borderColor="ffcc22" />
   <set label="Dark 2" value="30" isSliced="1" color="ffcc22" borderColor="ffcc22" />

   <set label="Light 3" value="69" isSliced="1" color="99ffdd" borderColor="33cc66" />
   <set label="Dark 3" value="31" isSliced="1" color="33cc66" borderColor="33cc66" />

   <set label="Light 4" value="86" isSliced="1" color="cceeff" borderColor="00aaee" />
   <set label="Dark 4" value="4" isSliced="1" color="00aaee" borderColor="00aaee" />
</chart>
```

As You can see, the values come in pairs (although the chart is single series - there is no multi-series pie3d), so in order to make the pairs visually distinguishable, i'm setting same border colors on related pairs of slices...
Everything looks fine, except the slice borders do not appear at all...

FC version is *FusionCharts XT v3.2.2*

Comment: Here's [link](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/11838-pie3d-slice-border/) to original question posted on fusioncharts support forum, in case it gets answered there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide `plotborderthickness='1'` in chart attributes as the plot borders have zero thickness by default for 3D charts. This is because under normal scenarios, 3D pie charts does not look that good when a border is applied.

**Updated XML would look like**

```
<chart
    decimals="1"
    plotBorderThickness="1" 
    enableSmartLabels="1"
    enableRotation="1"
    startingAngle="70"
    animation="1"
    defaultAnimation="1">

   <set label="Light 1" value="47" isSliced="1" color="ff9999" borderColor="dd3300" />
   <set label="Dark 1" value="53" isSliced="1" color="dd3300" borderColor="dd3300" />

   <set label="Light 2" value="68" isSliced="1" color="ffee99" borderColor="ffcc22" />
   <set label="Dark 2" value="30" isSliced="1" color="ffcc22" borderColor="ffcc22" />

   <set label="Light 3" value="69" isSliced="1" color="99ffdd" borderColor="33cc66" />
   <set label="Dark 3" value="31" isSliced="1" color="33cc66" borderColor="33cc66" />

   <set label="Light 4" value="86" isSliced="1" color="cceeff" borderColor="00aaee" />
   <set label="Dark 4" value="4" isSliced="1" color="00aaee" borderColor="00aaee" />
</chart>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: oh, You are right indeed... i already tried this one, but i did not notice it did change something, because there is additional parameter there - **plotBorderAlpha**, by default the borders are almost transparent, so setting **plotBorderAlpha** to 100 in addition made it opaque.